# как сделать скриншот того что видит бот с помощью библиотеки mineflayer

Tags: javascript, minecraft

Всем здраствуйте, это мой первый заданный вопрос. Я делаю бота используя библиотеку mineflayer и при попытке зайти на сервер получается естественно каптча в виде картин, все было бы легче если б картинка была одна. Я могу получать все картинки которые есть при заходе бота на сервер, но проблемма в том что они сохраняются абы как, тоесть некоторые верх дном, некоторые боком, и не получается быстро картинки так что бы получилось решить каптчу (приложил скрин как оно сохраняет)[image: screenshot]

Хотел сделать так что бы бот делал скриншот того что он видит на данный момент, но перерыв интернет и множество форумом ничего толкового не нашел. И библиотека prismarine-viewer не помогает с данной проблеммой, она просто не показывает картины хотя в настройках я указал параметр: showImages: true

Если найдется тот кто сможет мне помочь **заранее огромное спасибо!**